# Ebay api request error code 10009

Tags: python, ebay-api

I'm using the Ebay Python SDK
When I run this piece of code it prints the error:

ConnectionError: 'VerifyAddFixedPriceItem: Class: RequestError, Severity: Error, Code: 10009, No < Item.Currency > exists or < Item.Currency > is specified as an empty tag. No < Item.Currency > exists or < Item.Currency > is specified as an empty tag in the request., Class: RequestError, Severity: Error, Code: 10009, No < Item.Country > exists or < Item.Country > is specified as an empty tag. No < Item.Country > exists or < Item.Country > is specified as an empty tag in the request., Class: RequestError, Severity: Error, Code: 10009, No < Item.ListingDuration > exists or < Item.ListingDuration > is specified as an empty tag. No < Item.ListingDuration > exists or < Item.ListingDuration > is specified as an empty tag in the request.'

I'm fairly certain I specify the required parameters so don't understand why I get an error.

From the code:
'Country':            'US',
'Currency':           'USD',
'ListingDuration':    'GTC',

```
from ebaysdk.trading import Connection as Trading
api = Trading(domain='api.sandbox.ebay.com', config_file='ebay.yaml')

item = {
        'Title':   'Item Title',
        'Description': ' This is the description for the Item',
        'PrimaryCategory': {'CategoryID': '377'},
        'PrivateListing':     'True',
        'ConditionID':        '1000',
        'Country':            'US',
        'Currency':           'USD',
        'DispatchTimeMax':    '5',
        'ListingDuration':    'GTC',
        'ListingType':        'FixedPriceItem',
        'PaymentMethods':     'PayPal',
        'PayPalEmailAddress': 'xxx@gmail.com',
        'PictureDetails':     {
                                'PictureURL': 'picture_url',
                                'PhotoDisplay': 'SuperSize',
                              },
        'Location':           'Melbourne',
        'ReturnPolicy':     {
                                'ReturnsAcceptedOption': 'ReturnsAccepted',
                                'RefundOption': 'MoneyBack',
                                'ReturnsWithinOption': 'Days_30',
                                'Description': 'If you change your mind, please return your item within 30 days of recieving it for refund.',
                                'ShippingCostPaidByOption': 'Buyer'
                            },

        'ShippingDetails':    {

                            'ShippingType': 'Flat',
                            'ShippingServiceOptions':
                                {
                                    'FreeShipping': 'True',
                                    'ShippingService': 'AU_FastwayCouriers',
                                    'ShippingServiceCost': '0',
                                },
                            'InternationalShippingServiceOption': {
                                'FreeShipping': 'True',
                                'ShippingServiceCost': '0',
                                'ShippingService': 'AU_StandardInternational',
                                'ShippingServiceAdditionalCost': '0',
                                'ShippingServicePriority': '1',
                                'ShipToLocation': 'Worldwide',
                                }
                            }
   }

response = api.execute('VerifyAddFixedPriceItem', item)

print(response.reply)
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument to VerifyAddFixedPriceItem should be specified as a dictionary ie

```
response = api.execute('VerifyAddFixedPriceItem', {'item': item})
```